# Plot legend using nested ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, nested

Here’s the problem, I would like to make a plot using only the R basic functions. The idea is to make a scatterplot where each point represents a country. This data set is updated every so often and not all countries are present every time.

I want to define the colours that each country gets. So far so good I can do this using some nested ifelse statements.   However ,if you run the example below a few times you’ll see that the colours not always correspond to what was defined. I’ve tried to sort it out but I simply can’t fix it. I’m sure it is something silly but at the moment I can’t work it out.

```
  dat <- data.frame(Country=sample(c("Scotland","Sweeden","Ireland","Netherlands"),
10,replace=T),x =sample( 1:10,10),y= sample( 1:10,10))

plot(dat$x,dat$y,pch=20,cex=2,col=ifelse(dat$Country=="Scotland","darkblue",
ifelse(dat$Country=="Netherlands","orange",ifelse(dat$Country=="Ireland","green",
ifelse(dat$Country=="France","red",ifelse(dat$Country=="Sweeden","yellow","Black"))))))

legend("bottomleft",legend=unique(dat$Country),col=ifelse(dat$Country=="Scotland",
"darkblue",ifelse(dat$Country=="Netherlands","orange",ifelse(dat$Country=="Ireland",
"green",ifelse(dat$Country=="France","red",ifelse(dat$Country=="Sweeden","yellow",
"Black"))))),pch=20,cex=1, bty = "n")
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Patrao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the colors to a different data.frame, you can easily acces them without the ifelse:

```
dat <- data.frame(Country=sample(c("Scotland","Sweeden","Ireland","Netherlands"),
                             10,replace=T),x =sample( 1:10,10),y= sample( 1:10,10))

colorFrame <- data.frame(Country=c("Scotland","Sweeden","Ireland","Netherlands","France"),
                     Color = c("darkblue","yellow","green","orange","red"))

dat <- merge(dat,colorFrame)

plot(dat$x,dat$y,pch=20,cex=2,col=as.vector(dat$Color))

legend("bottomleft",legend=colorFrame[which(colorFrame$Country %in% unique(dat$Country)),]$Country,col=as.vector(colorFrame[which(colorFrame$Country %in% unique(dat$Country)),]$Color),pch=20,cex=1, bty = "n")
```

Comment: this way the legend is still showing all possibilities not only what is displayed in the plot (i.e. France is in the legend despite not being in the plot) also for some reason the colors shown in both plot and legend are not the defined ones (almost like being random generated)

Comment: I've edited so that only present countries are shown, by subsetting on present countries. I have fixed that exact colors are shown, by converting to a vector.

Comment: I'm affraid that it is not right yet again the colors are not matching the defined ones if you run this line after the code you will see what I mean text(dat$x,dat$y, labels=dat$Country, cex= 0.7)

Comment: What if you put as.vector around dat$color as well?

Comment: that solved the problem. Manny thanks for your help. Could you please edit your solution so others could more easily use the code. Cheers